# Developing Chrome Extension from inside the Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use TamperMonkey. I am considering creating a personal Chrome Extension to overcome the limitation of TamperMonkey. It will be used only by me. Is there anyway I can develop them from inside the Chrome like TamperMonkey scripts so I can save time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add your extension's folder as [a workspace in Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/workspace/setup-workflow)
2. Now you can edit it inside the devtools which has lots of useful hotkeys and functions, see [Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and [Authoring & development workflow](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow).
3. Load the unpacked extension on `chrome://extensions` page, the button will appear if the `[x] Developer mode` checkbox is ticked.
4. To reload the changes in your background and content scripts use `Reload` link in the extension infobox on `chrome://extensions` page (you'll have to reopen any background inspectors opened as described in #6)
5. To reload the changes in a popup/page-action simply rightclick the button and choose `Inspect popup` - a new window will open where you can make *temporary* changes to the code (edit something and press Ctrl-S) and reload the popup (Ctrl-R or F5)
6. To inspect the background page use the aforementioned `chrome://extensions` page and click the `background` page link which will open a new window where you can make *temporary* changes to the code (edit something and press Ctrl-S) and reload the background page (Ctrl-R or F5)
7. Use [the debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) extensively, it's especially useful to intercept messages sent from the background page to a content script or a popup page script and vice versa.